# Log4j2 Routing Context variable WildFly

Tags: dependencies, wildfly, log4j2, appender

Working with WildFly9 and log4j2 used in my deployed application i get this error:

```
20:12:36,376 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-async) 2016-06-16 20:12:36,376 AsyncAppender-async ERROR Unable to create file D:/logs/${ctx:tenant}/${ctx:tenant}.log java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
20:12:36,380 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-async)       at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
20:12:36,380 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-async)       at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1012)
20:12:36,380 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-async)       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:409)
20:12:36,381 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-async)       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.RollingFileManager$RollingFileManagerFactory.createManager(RollingFileManager.java:391)
20:12:36,382 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-async)       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AbstractManager.getManager(AbstractManager.java:73)
20:12:36,383 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-async)       at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.OutputStreamManager.getManager(OutputStreamManager.java:80)
20:12:36,383 INFO  [stdout] (AsyncAppender-async)       at
```

The configuration is this:

```
<configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
      <Routing name="RoutingAppender">
        <Routes pattern="$${ctx:tenant}">
            <Route>
                <RollingFile name="Rolling-${ctx:tenant}"
                    fileName="D:/logs/${ctx:tenant}/${ctx:tenant}.log"
                    filePattern="D:/logs/${ctx:tenant}/$${date:yyyy-MM}/iii-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz">
                    <PatternLayout
                        pattern="%d{ABSOLUTE} %level{length=5} [%thread] %logger{1} - %msg%n" />
                    <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB" />
                </RollingFile>
            </Route>
            <Async name="async" bufferSize="1000" includeLocation="true">
                <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender" />           
            </Async>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="INFO">         
            <AppenderRef ref="RoutingAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

What could be the error?

Answer (score 0):

Something strange is going on here. Your fileName pattern is logs/${ctx:tenant} and yet the file it can't create is D:/logs/${ctx:tenant}/${ctx:tenant}.log, which obviously isn't that same as the file name your are showing in he configuration.

Unfortunately, you have cut off both the log and the configuration at a point that I can't really tell what is going on. I'd like to see what if just before the error and more of the stack trace, and all of the configuration.

Comment: It still doesn't match. The file that cannot be created is D:/logs/${ctx:tenant}/${ctx:tenant}.log but the fileName is D:/logs/${ctx:tenant}/mylog.log.

Comment: Based on what you have shown it would appear that "tenant" is not being stored in the thread context for the thread being logged. You only have one Route, which is configured to be the default, so tenant has to always be defined or you will see the error you are getting.

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm facing the same issue.